# Host my bot locally using offline-directline package

Tags: c#, html, node.js, iis, botframework

I am looking to host my bot developed with Microsoft bot framework using C # locally, I found this package https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline-directline, I tried to apply what is mentioned in the documentation, here is what I did.
1-Create a new node project: [image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

2-Build a bot: I created an echo bot just for testing, and hosted it using iis.
[image: pic3]

3-Set up your client: in this section, I added an html file, and I created BotChat.App
[image: pic4]
have two questions The file index. Html, I put it in the same folder of index.js is that correct? If it was yes why when I grab http: // localhost: 8000 / samples / fullwindow /? domain = http: // localhost: 3000 / directLine does not work ??

Comment: Please put your code snippet here in place of images. It would make your question much clearer.

Comment: you could refer thi slink for more detail about how to use the offline-directline: https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline-directline , https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat ,https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle

Comment: Were you able to fix it?